# MS Outlook removes original Email address from "From" field when forwarding received Gmail delegate email

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail

This is the scenario:

- Delegate of Gmail account sends an email to customer from within delegated Gmail account
- Customer receives the email "From: Delegated Account
  delegated.account@domain.com" and forwards the email **with MS Outlook** to
  colleague
- Colleague receives the email "From: delegate@domain.com On Behalf of Delegate Account" - the delegated.account@domain.com email address is stripped from this email's "From" information.
- Colleague replies to the email and the reply is sent to the account
  of delegate@domain.com instead of to delegated.account@domain.com

After several discussions with G Suite Support the conclusion is that on the G Suite/Gmail side everything is working correctly. For some reason MS Outlook is not respecting the originating email address in the "From" fields of the emails it is forwarding.

We have tested this with Thunderbird and with Gmail itself, and could not reproduce the problem.
At this point we have to assume that the problem is with MS Outlook.

Has anyone else had this problem, and if so was there any solution/workaround?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, the delegate feature in the Outlook desktop client only supports Exchange email accounts. Also, when forwarding emails to other users, the from fields will only show the current sender and you can only see the information of "From: delegate@domain.com On Behalf of Delegate Account" in the message body. If this is your case, I'm afraid that it is by design and we could not make changes to it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the impression that this also happens if Gmail is used as a mail server and the original mail is sent to a group address (for example to `group@example.com`, if this is set up as a Gmail group on the an `example.com` domain managed by Gmail). When such an email is forwarded with Outlook the original sender (i.e. `From` field) is shown like:

```
From: group@example.com <group@example.com> On Behalf Of Firstname Lastname
```

Where `Firstname Lastname` is the name of the original sender.

So, instead of showing the original sender's email it shows up as `group@example.com`. This only happens if the mail is forwarded in Outlook. If instead the mail is forwarded in Gmail, the original sender's address is correctly shown in the From field.

We have an `info@...` address that is set up as a group in Gmail and this is very annoying.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1192029)